# logstash : create fingerprint from timestamp part

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, fingerprinting

I have a problem to create a fingerprint based on client-ip and a timestamp containing date+hour. 
I'm using logstash 7.3.1. Here it the relevant part of my configuration file

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date{ 
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
  ...
  ruby{
    code => "
      keydate = Date.parse(event.get('timestamp'))
      event.set('keydate', keydate.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H'))
    "
  }
  fingerprint {
    key => "my_custom_secret"
    method => "SHA256"
    concatenate_sources => "true"
    source => [
      "clientip",
      "keydate"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is into the 'ruby' block. I tried multiple methods to compute the keydate, but none works without giving me errors.
The last one (using this config file) is

```
[ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: Missing Converter handling for full class name=org.jruby.ext.date.RubyDateTime, simple name=RubyDateTime
```

**input document**

```
{
      "timestamp" => "19/Sep/2019:00:07:56 +0200",
       "referrer" => "-",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => 2019-09-18T22:07:56.000Z,
             ...
        "request" => "index.php",
           "type" => "apache_access",
       "clientip" => "54.157.XXX.XXX",
           "verb" => "GET",
             ...
           "tags" => [
              [0] "_rubyexception"  # generated by the ruby exception above
           ],
       "response" => "200"
}
```

**expected output**

```
{
      "timestamp" => "19/Sep/2019:00:07:56 +0200",
       "referrer" => "-",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => 2019-09-18T22:07:56.000Z,
             ...
        "request" => "index.php",
           "type" => "apache_access",
       "clientip" => "54.157.XXX.XXX",
           "verb" => "GET",
             ...
        "keydate" => "20190919-00", #format : YYYYMMDD-HH
    "fingerprint" => "ab347766ef....1190af",
       "response" => "200"
}
```

As always, many thanks for all your help !

Comment: Can you change this line `keydate = Date.parse(event.get('timestamp'))` to this: `keydate = Date.parse(event.get('timestamp').to_s)`.
 
Or you can try to set event without using `Date.parse` function like this: `event.set('keydate', Date.strptime('timestamp', '%Y%m%d-%H'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to remove the ruby snippet and use the build in Date filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html

What you are doing in the ruby snippet is exactly what the date filter does - extract a timestamp from a field and reconstruct it into your desire format.

another option (a bit less recommended, but will also work) is to use grok in order to extract the relevant parts of the timestamp and combine them in a different manner.